# ADF-JMeter error : “ViewExpiredException. Because of inactivity, your session has timed out and is no longer active. “

Tags: jmeter, oracle-adf

I am working on Apache JMeter 2.10 to record an ADF application deployed on WebLogic Server version 10.3.6. Our application is developed using JDeveloper version is 11.1.2.4. We are calling Task flows as pop-up at certain places in the application. On running the recorded JMeter scripts, the execution fails giving ViewExpiredException in the response data of the HTTP Request(Exception details are  given below). This is caused as the value for ‘javax.faces.ViewState’  changes on encountering a task flow. Kindly help me with how can this be resolved while recording the JMeter scripts.

ADF_FACES-30107:The view state of the page has expired.  Reload the page.
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._restoreView(LifecycleImpl.java:726)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:349)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)

Answer (score 0):

This is called **correlation**, you need to extract ViewState from each request and add it to next request to match page state level changes.

In order to achieve this you need to add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) Post Processor to each request

Use ReferenceName, i.e. `jsfViewState`

Regular Expression

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="(.+?)" />
```

And template `$1$`

For the previous request.

And make sure that you're passing following parameter for the next request:

```
javax.faces.ViewState=${jsfViewState}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm still getting ViewExpiredException

Comment: The scenario that I'm recording goes like this - When my scripts starts it has let say ViewState-1, then in between the viw state changes to ViewState-2, after which again the ViewState-1 is restored. Further proceeding i get ViewState-3. After few samples it again restores ViewState-1 and so on. I followed what you said but still I'm facing the error. I also tried to skip adding post-processor to the places where the ViewState changes. But the same result.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the following lines to web.xml made the trick:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread Group --> Add --> ConfigElement --> HTTPCookieRequest and enable Clear cookies each iteration. Below is the image of HttpCookiemanager where you can take it for reference.

[image]